# How to combine two lists by concatenating pairs of parallel elements?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists like this:

```
list_a = ["Orange", "Kiwi", "Apple", "Orange"]
list_b = ["sweet", "bitter", "nice", "good for skin"]
```

How to concatenate the two lists to become like this:

```
list_c = ["Orange", "sweet", "Kiwi", "bitter", "Apple", "nice", "Orange", "good for skin"]
```

What I got is just adding the last element.

Comment: "*Note: Please help using Python or maybe JavaScript is fine.*" These two languages are executed entirely differently. How would one be of assistance instead of the other...? What is your broader project using?

Comment: Also note that Stack Overflow is not tutorial service, nor intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Comment: note: I never copying it from internet sir, it just an analogy, but thanks for the reminder

I'm stupid and still a newbie, please take care of me, sir, I will learn it more. Thanks for the rating @mkrieger1

Comment: thanks for your recommendation, next time I will do more better question @esqew

Comment: Thank you sir, I will learn more about it, and helping other, really thanks, sorry for my stupidness @martineau

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer @martineau, next time I would like to giving more time finding the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both the lists have same length.

```py
list_a = ["Orange", "Kiwi", "Apple", "Orange"]
list_b = ["sweet", "bitter", "nice", "good for skin"]

list_c = []
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    list_c.append(a)
    list_c.append(b)

print(list_c)
```

Output:

```py
['Orange', 'sweet', 'Kiwi', 'bitter', 'Apple', 'nice', 'Orange', 'good for skin']
```

Comment: `.extend` is probably a cleaner solution than two `.append`s.